# Getting the line number of the cursor in the Excel VBE ActiveCodePane

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the line number of the cursor in the VBE ActiveCodeWindow. Can that be done?

When I'm in the VBE, there is an edit/text widget (in the Standard toolbar) that shows the *line number* and the column of the cursor position, so I know that VBA is keeping track of that. So how do I expose that functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the VBE through the *Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility* model. This is denied by default because it's a common vector for malicious office documentation.

If you enable this feature, you are allowing malicious VBA code to be crafted on the fly in a way that virus scanners can't detect. For this reason, it is advised to never use these features. Any computer that your code runs on would need this security feature disabled.

Source: *[Programmatic access to Office VBA project is denied](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282830/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied)*

The MSDN documentation says that it's possible using a method called: [`GetSelection`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getselection-method-vba-add-in-object-model)

You would run this on the [`ActiveCodePane`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/visual-basic-add-in-model/properties-visual-basic-add-in-model#activecodepane), passing in variables that will be populated with the return values.

#### Example

```
Dim startline As Long
Dim startcol As Long
Dim endline As Long
Dim endcol As Long

Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection startline, startcol, endline, endcol

Debug.Print "Line: " & startline
Debug.Print "Column: " & startcol
```

#### Additional reading

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the example HackSlash, that and SetSelection will get me where I want to go. As for running the code as is, it is only for me at work and at home. Never going into the wild and i keep my PC locked down.

Comment: @DanM, more specifically the way you mitigate this threat is: **Never open a macro enabled document that you get from an external source. Doesn't matter who sent it to you or where you downloaded it.**